# Splitting a column in two while leaving the original

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe formatted like this in pandas.

```
(df)
School ID      Column 1 
School 1       AD6000         
School 2       3000TO4000      
School 3       5000TO6000      
School 4       AC2000         
School 5       BB3300        
School 6       9000TO9900      
....
```

All I want to do is Split columns that have the word 'TO' in it as a delimiter into two new columns in a new DF, but every time I do it it also edits the original Column 1.

```
(NewDF)
School ID      Column 1          Column 2     Column 3
School 1       AD6000            NaN          NaN
School 2       3000TO4000        3000         4000
School 3       5000TO6000        5000         6000
School 4       AC2000            NaN          NaN
School 5       BB3300            NaN          NaN
School 6       9000TO9900        9000         9900
....
```

Here's the code I have been trying.

```
NewDF = df1['Column 1']
NewDF[['Column 2', 'Column 3']] = df1['Column 1'].str.split('TO\s+', expand=True, n=1)
```

While this makes two new columns, it just puts the info in column 1 into column 2, without splitting the string. I then tried

```
NewDF[['Column 2','Column 3']] = NewDF['Column 2'].str.split('TO',expand=True, n=1)
```

And I get the error "Columns must be same length as key".

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I will use `.str.extract`:

```
df[['Column 2','Column 3']] = df['Column 1'].str.extract(r'(\d+)TO(\d+)')
```

Comment: edit: Actually, it is leaving NaNs in Columns 2 and 3 where numbers are supposed to be.